# How to set new GameObject as child of Components GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, unity3d-editor

I want to create an empty `GameObject` that is a child of the Components `GameObject`.

Example:
I have a simple spline and I am using the child objects as the control points. I have a button to add new control points which uses the following code to create a new object and should also set the new `GameObject` as a child of the scripts object.

```
public void addNewNode()
{
   var g = new GameObject();
   g.transform.parent = this.transform;
}
```

This implementation does not work and does not show the object in the inspector which I assume means something went wrong and the object was destroyed.

Edit:

To test that setting parent was working properly I printed the name of `g` parent transform. It printed the correct name so I think the problem is that setting the parent is not being reflected in the editor. NOTE: I am using a `[CustomEditor()]` script in addition to the `MonoBehaviour` script if this effects something with unity.

Edit 2 - Minimal Full Code:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(SplineManager))]
public class SplineManagerInspector : Editor {

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    SplineManager spMngr = (SplineManager)target;

    // additional code to add public variables

    if (GUILayout.Button ("Add New Node")) {
        spMngr.addNewNode ();
        EditorUtility.SetDirty (target);
    }

    // code to add some public variables

    if (GUI.changed) {
        spMngr.valuesChanged ();
        EditorUtility.SetDirty (target);
    }
}
}


[RequireComponent (typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class SplineManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SplineContainer splineContainer = new SplineContainer ();
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private GameObject gObj;

    // additional code to deal with spline events/actions.

    public void addNewNode ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("new node");
        gObj = new GameObject ();
        gObj.transform.parent = this.gameObject.transform;  // this does not work... (shows nothing)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Debug your own code before posting these type of question. Put `Debug.Log` in that function and see if it shows up. Remove the `g.transform.parent = this.transform;` and see if the newly created objects is now visialbe in the Hierarchy tab. It will be better to name the newly created object so that you can easily find it `var g = new GameObject("THE NAME");`

Comment: If I remove `g.transform.parent = this.transform` the gameObject shows up just find but I need it to be a child of the SplineManager (the gameObject that holds the scripts creating the new nodes.

Comment: You current script should do just that. I suggest you try the [SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) function and see what happens. If that did not work too then you should post the complete code exactly how it is + the Inspector tab screenshot of the GameObject it is attached to and also the Hierarchy tab of this GameObject when you click "Run".

Comment: @Programmer I have added a small amount of the code to show the structure of the classes/functions used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void addNewNode( GameObject parentOb)
{
    GameObject childOb = new GameObject("name");
    childOb.transform.SetParent(parentOb);
}
```

or

```
private GameObject childObj;
private GameObject otherObj;

public void addNewNode()
{
    childObj = new GameObject("name");
    // in case you want the new gameobject to be a child of the gameobject that your script is attached to
    childObj.transform.parent = this.gameObject.transform;
    // we can use .SetParent as well
    otherObj.transform.SetParent(childObj);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest use [SetParent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) method.

Comment: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) check this out and make sure your orientation as expected.

Comment: This answer is actually correct. I have a bug where I checked if values were changed which removed the children. Long story short this solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Well I am glad it helped mate :)